# How to post dynamically added form fields to mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, dynamic

I have dynamically added form fields and I need to post them to DB.

Here is the jquery that generates the fields

```
                // set unique name for inputs
                .find('input').each(function(index) {
                    $(this).attr('name','input_'+ tr_length + '_' + (index + 1))
                })
                .end()
                // set unique name for selects
                .find('select').each(function(index) {
                    $(this).attr('name','select_'+ tr_length + '_' + (index + 1))
                });
```

Here is the output

```
<input type="text" name="input_2_1" />
```

and

```
<select name="select_2_1"></select>
```

Could you please help me to post these fields to DB

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe best to set up an EAV table for handling this type of data.
An example of EAV might look like this..

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id int not null primary key auto_increment,
  email varchar(244) not null
);

CREATE TABLE user_attributes(
   id int not null primary key auto_increment,
   user_id int not null references users(id),
   attribute_name varchar(40) not null,
   attribute_value varchar(200) not null
);
```

The to retrieve the data for a user..
SELECT * FROM users u JOIN user_attributes ua ON a.id=ua.user_id;

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I was expecting a less complex solution as I am not a skilled programmer.